# How to access multiple streams inside a StreamBuilder?

Tags: flutter, stream-builder

I've tried to make a new `StreamBuilder` inside the builder of my initial stream, and while I don't get any errors, it also doesn't seem like it works. Is this possible to do?

Basically, I'm accessing a root Collection in Firebase. This collection contains two documents, and I need data from each of them, as I am building a DataTable that contains information from both paths.

EDIT: The nested StreamBuilder doesn't work because StreamBuilder must return a widget, so at least I know why it wasn't working. But I still don't have a resolution on what to do.

Comment: You can combine streams in various ways. The `rxdart` package provides a large set of stream transformers for that purpose, the `async` from the Dart team provides a few as well.

Comment: You could combine using StreamZip or StreamGroup and with the combined stream you use .asBroadcastStream()

Answer (score 1):

you can use it like this:

```
    StreamBuilder(
        stream: firestore.collection("nameofcollection").doc.snapshots(),
        buider: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot){
            if(snapshot.hasError) return Text('your error');
                if(snapshot.hasData){  
                    typeList List nameList = [];
                    snapshot.forEach((e){
                        typeObject object = ();
                        object.property1 = e.get('property1Database');
                        object.property2 = e.get('property2Database');
                        nameList.add(object);
                    });
                    //now use the list that will be loaded with the 2 documents
                 }
            }
    );
```

Comment: in line snapshot.forEach((e){  , read snapshot.doc.forEach((e){

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [StreamZip](https://pub.dev/documentation/async/latest/async/StreamZip-class.html)? This should help you manage multiple streams. Here's a sample on how it could be used.

```dart
import 'package:async/async.dart';

Stream<DocumentSnapshot> stream1 = firestore.document('/path1').snapshots();
Stream<DocumentSnapshot> stream2 = firestore.document('/path2').snapshots();
StreamZip bothStreams = StreamZip([stream1, stream2]);

// To use stream
bothStreams.listen((snaps) {
 DocumentSnapshot snapshot1 = snaps[0];
 DocumentSnapshot snapshot2 = snaps[1];

 // ...
});
```

Do you have a [minimal repro](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you're trying to implement along with the steps to replicate the behavior? I also need how the data you're trying to access looks like. This will help me visualize how you're trying to run multiple streams for Firestore (I assumed since `Collection` was mentioned).